# Screen sharing Application in C# for Windows Xp with using RDP Viewer Class Component

Tags: c#, remoting, remote-desktop

I am trying to develop Basic Screen Sharing Application for in C# language for windows Xp.

I have develop Basic Application with using **RDPCOMAPILib**  means **rdpcomapi 1.0 type library**

and **RDPViewer Class Component**. its works fine on windows 7 but its not work on windows XP because its not find **RDPViewer Class Component** I have created two module for this first for host and Second is Viewer In host its generate unique code which use for connect to remote computer. My code is below

> using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
>
> using RDPCOMAPILib;

```
    RDPSession x = new RDPSession();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Incoming(object Guest)
    {
        IRDPSRAPIAttendee MyGuest = (IRDPSRAPIAttendee)Guest;//???
        MyGuest.ControlLevel = CTRL_LEVEL.CTRL_LEVEL_INTERACTIVE;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x.OnAttendeeConnected += Incoming;
        x.Open();

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IRDPSRAPIInvitation Invitation = x.Invitations.CreateInvitation("Trial", "MyGroup", "", 10);
        textBox1.Text = Invitation.ConnectionString;

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x.Close();
        x = null;

    }
```

And Viewer Code is

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Invitation = textBox1.Text;// "";// Interaction.InputBox("Insert Invitation ConnectionString", "Attention");
        axRDPViewer1.Connect(Invitation, "User1", "");

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axRDPViewer1.Disconnect();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - 100;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN articles for [IRDPSRAPIAttendee](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [IRDPSRAPIInvitation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373294%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the APIs that you are trying to use are only available on Windows Vista and later. Thus, I don't think you'll be able them on Windows XP.

Comment: does any idea how can i do for windows xp i did  googling but didn't get any solution